# Keycloak modify existing action token spi

Tags: java, single-sign-on, openid-connect, keycloak, keycloak-services

Need to modify existing action token handlers for **Verify-email / reset-password** action token handlers. I tied extending `AbstractActionTokenHander` for verify email and registered in `org.keycloak.authentication.actiontoken.ActionTokenHandlerFactory`. Class loaded when launching keycloak, but still its using already existing class instead of implemented one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reset password flow create new authenticator and modify authentication flow.

1) Create new Authenticator by implementing `Authenticator, AuthenticatorFactory` or modify existing code in `org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.resetcred.ResetCredentialEmail`

2) Define Authenticator class info in `org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticatorFactory` file.

3) Deploy jar and Copy **Reset credential authenticator** flow and replace new authenticator with **Send reset email** execution

Comment: Do you have an example of the new ResetCredentialEmail?  I tried something like:class InternalUserResetCredentialEmail extends ResetCredentialEmail {
  import InternalUserResetCredentialEmail._

  override def authenticate(context: AuthenticationFlowContext): Unit = {
    val user: UserModel = context.getUser()

    logger.debug(s"InternalUserResetCredentialEmail.authenticate($context): user: $user, user.isInternalUser: ${user.isInternalUser}")
    if (user.isInternalUser) super.authenticate(context)
  }

  override def getId(): String = InternalUserResetCredentialEmail.ProviderId
}